# Getting 2-factor Gmail authentication code from USA mobile number

Tags: gmail, passwords, multi-factor-auth

I have been facing a serious problem for many months. Usually I get a 2-factor authentication code from 51501 when I am supposed to log into Gmail. But for months I am getting a code from a USA-based mobile number: +15155327373. When I call this number, the ring goes on and on and no one picks up, I am facing this problem since October 2015.

There is also a mobile number from Sweden - +46701327805 that sometimes sends the code. I change my passwords every time this happens. What could be the possible reason for this and how to overcome this problem?

By the way,
- I must say I have been hacked for years.
- I don't use VPN; my internet runs off a broadband modem.

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Comment: @MartinSchröder No, I plan to ask them today.

Comment: @MartinSchröder It was asked by me only.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that the number is only used to send you a code. I doubt you would be able to call the number to speak with someone.

You should consider a hardware key like the Yubikey for a second factor. SMS (and your phone number) are vulnerable to being stolen which could give a hacker access to your account. https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/

If you have a smartphone (iPhone, Android), consider using Google Authenticator to generate the second factor code since this does not require a text or phone connection. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447